# efficient ajax queries for multiple bits of information

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

For learning, I'm making a tic tac toe game that's intended to be played between two users online.  It uses PHP and MySQL, and lots of jquery and ajax on the frontend.

During a game, players will see the tic tac toe board, and an indication of who's turn it is.  It will use ajax/jquery to update all of this info without page refreshes - at least that is my intent.

I need to have it query for each field of the board.  I can fairly simply do this with nine different routines, but that seems terribly inefficient.  Can a jquery ajax procedure be written which will hit the php/sql backend and get updates for all nine cells?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look into [json](http://www.json.org/) - your php can return a single string representing an object that contains as much information as you want (well, within reason). Using jQuery.getJSON(), the string will automagically be read into a javascript object, and the javascript on your page can read the info from the object at will.